# What is the name for a video that is shown as a preamble to an interview on a talk show?

Tags: terminology, translation

In TV talk shows, what is the name for a video clip that is shown as a preamble to an interview? I am working in the Netherlands, where they call this an 'instart'.

Comment: You mean one which has a short profile of the guest? Or where they show a clip of a new feature film or TV series before an actor appears to talk about their role in the film/series? Some kind of humorous skit that acts as an informal introduction (maybe in a style that's specific to the show)? Footage of their arrival/entry to the theatre/studio? Or some more general video that's not specific to a guest? Is the purpose to provide information to the viewer, to entertain, or just to cover up the time it takes the guest to walk onto stage and sit down?

Answer (score 1):

It is often called ***Intro Video***:

> An intro video is a short, direct, introductory video that tells the viewer everything they need to know about your product/service and business while also setting the tone for your brand and the rest of your content.

Comment: Have you references showing that this is not just a business term? I'm thinking of the location shots of a city say before a TV news reporter interviews (at 2m distancing at present) locals about an issue.

Comment: This is not so much a term from corporate videos, but rather from mainstream TV (entertainment or current affairs). So, for example, before an interviewee is interviewed, they show a short clip (possibly challenging the interviewee) to set the tone.

Comment: @DaveH - TV Intro video are commonly used in mainstream TV

Comment: I work for a media company. Internally, we use the term **intro** and **outro** for short videos that are at the beginning and ending (respectively) of a segment.

Comment: It may be an intro to segment coverage and highlights, in which case it can also be called a teaser.

Comment: You used the term _'introductory'_ in your sentence that states what an _`Intro Video`_ is, but to me it sounds better to actually call such a video an `Introductory Video`. Obviously, this is just my own opinion. I have always called them _introductory videos_, and I certainly know that I may be wrong about this. I thought it was worth mentioning though.